# I cannot add to my sqlite database . Please advise 

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

```
filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
sqlite3_stmt *insertstatement=nil;

NSString *cruddatabase = [self.GetDocumentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SalaryBook.sqlite"];

sqlite3_open([cruddatabase UTF8String], &SalaryBook);

const char *sql = "insert into contactDB (name, designation, address, phone ,email ,identification, picture, doj) ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(SalaryBook, sql, 1, &insertstatement, NULL);

sqlite3_bind_text(insertstatement,0,[theContact.name UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(insertstatement,1,[theContact.designation UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(insertstatement,2,[theContact.address UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(insertstatement,3,[theContact.phoneNumber UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

NSLog(@"%@",theContact.phoneNumber);

sqlite3_bind_text(insertstatement,4,[theContact.emailAddress UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(insertstatement,5,[theContact.identificationProof UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

NSData *dataForPicture = UIImagePNGRepresentation(theContact.image);

sqlite3_bind_blob(insertstatement,6,[dataForPicture bytes],[dataForPicture length],SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(insertstatement,7,[theContact.dateOfJoining UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

sqlite3_step(insertstatement);
sqlite3_finalize(insertstatement);

sqlite3_close(SalaryBook);
```

I can read from the database but can't write anything to it.

Comment: Dunno anything about objective-c but should it not be `VALUES(?,?,? ...`

Comment: Can't you use coredata? It's easier and your code will look cleaner. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreData_ObjC/_index.html

Comment: change your insert to just one value first to debug.  I had similar issues some time ago.  I stepped back to one insert to ensure all was correct.  (i.e. work with name first).

Answer (score 0):

Format of insert string is..
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)

So replace this in the string (double quotes) & try...
insert into contactDB (name, designation, address, phone ,email ,identification, picture, doj) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)